# AudioContext of Web Audio API is not exist in Chrome beta 29 of Android 4.0 tablet

Tags: google-chrome, html5-audio, webrtc, webkitaudiocontext

I use the AudioContext of web audio api and I install the chrome beta 29 version in my android 4.0 tablet(Samsung P7510), But Javascript will throw the exception "AudioContext is undefine", but on chrome beta 29 PC version, it is work fine. And even if I test it on my cell phone, it is ok too.

```
context = new webkitAudioContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

try context = new AudioContext();

Answer (score 0):

I generally make several test, to use the correct syntax!

```
 audioContext = window.AudioContext ? new window.AudioContext() :
           window.webkitAudioContext ? new window.webkitAudioContext() :
           window.mozAudioContext ? new window.mozAudioContext() :
           window.oAudioContext ? new window.oAudioContext() :
           window.msAudioContext ? new window.msAudioContext() :
           undefined;
```